# z ordering of elements qt qml

Tags: qt, embedded, qml

I'm struggling with an issue and I can't find a solution.
I am developing an embedded device (a graphic interface for an oven) with Qt.
I have the main page where I have a SwipeView with a grid inside to show n-tiles.
The tile is defined in another object.qml that I call in the main page and on each tile I have an image with 3 dots and when you click on it, a popup comes out that lets you edit the tile.
The problem is showing this popup because when I click on the three-dot-image the popup object shows underneath the tile and I can't seem to solve this problem.
I tried changing the z property but it doesn't work.
Anyway, I'm gonna attach some code and two images of the interface.

Thank you

[image]
[image]

MyPgRecipeGrid.qml this is my main page

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

SwipeView {
        id: view

        property int numProgrammi : myVar.progCategoryRecipeGrid.count

        currentIndex: 0
        width:parent.width
        height: parent.height*0.75
        anchors.top: searchRect.bottom; anchors.topMargin: parent.height*0.025

        Repeater {
            id: gridRepeat
            property int numgrid: ((Math.floor(view.numProgrammi/12)) + (((view.numProgrammi%12)==0) ? 0 : 1))

            model: numgrid

            delegate:  Rectangle {
                color: "transparent"

                GridView {
                    id:grid
                    width: parent.width*0.95; height: parent.height
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

                    clip: false

                    property int numPage: index

                    cellWidth: 190; cellHeight: 180
                    interactive: false
                    model: 12 //Draws 12 tiles

                    delegate: Rectangle {

                        width: grid.cellWidth; height: grid.cellHeight
                        color: "transparent"

                        TileCategoryRecipeGrid {

                            property int indicelista: ((grid.numPage * 12)+index < myVar.progCategoryRecipeGrid.count) ? ((grid.numPage * 12 )+index) : 0

                            visible: ((grid.numPage*12)+index) < view.numProgrammi ? true : false

                            nomeTypCat: qsTr(myVar.progCategoryRecipeGrid.get(indexlist).nameCategory)
                            urlimageTypCat: myVar.progCategoryRecipeGrid.get(indexlist).urlCategoryImage
                            emptyTypCat: myVar.progCategoryRecipeGrid.get(indexlist).emptyCategory
                            userTypCat: myVar.progCategoryRecipeGrid.get(indexlist).userCategory

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

TileCategoryRecipeGrid.qml this is where I build the tile

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

//Tile
Button{

    id: tileCategoryRecipeGrid
    width: 180; height: 172

    property string myFont: myVar.medium
    property string myFont2: myVar.fontTile

    background: Rectangle {

        anchors.fill: parent;
        color: "transparent"; radius: 2
        opacity: parent.down ? 0.80 : 1
        clip: true

        Image {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter; anchors.verticalCenterOffset: -10
            source: image
            }
        }
    }

    Button{
        id: btnPoints
        width: 35; height: 35
        anchors.right: parent.right; anchors.rightMargin: 3
        anchors.top: parent.top; anchors.topMargin: 3

        background: Rectangle {
            id: threePoints
            anchors.fill: parent;
            color: "transparent";
            opacity: parent.down ? 0.25 : 1

            Image {
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: contextMenu.visible ? "qrc:/QmlContents/IMG/close_btn.png" : "qrc:/QmlContents/IMG/threepoints.png"
            }
        }
        onClicked: {

            contextMenu.visible == false ? contextMenu.visible = true : contextMenu.visible = false
            indexLocationPopup = index
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: showCookingTime
        anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.leftMargin: 42
        anchors.top: parent.top; anchors.topMargin: 3
        text: qsTr("00:20"); color: clrPaletta.white
        font.family: myFont; font.pixelSize: 20
    }

    contentItem: Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: parent; opacity: parent.down ? 0.80 : 1
        color: "transparent"

        Text{
            color: clrPaletta.white; opacity: 0.50
            text:  qsTr("cooking type")
            font.family: myFont ; font.pixelSize: 17
            anchors.left: parent.left ; anchors.leftMargin: parent.width*0.05
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom; anchors.bottomMargin: parent.height*0.10
        }

        //Popup edit tile
            ContextMenuEditTile {
                id: contextMenu
                visible: false
                x: {
                    switch(indexLocationPopup) {
                    case 0: dp(parent.width*0.60); break
                    case 1: -dp(parent.width-parent.width*0.70); break
                    case 2: -dp(parent.width-parent.width*0.70); break
                    case 3: dp(parent.width*0.60); break
                    case 4: -dp(parent.width-parent.width*0.70); break
                    case 5: -dp(parent.width-parent.width*0.70); break
                    case 6: dp(parent.width*0.60); break
                    case 7: -dp(parent.width-parent.width*0.70); break
                    case 8: -dp(parent.width-parent.width*0.70); break
                    case 9: dp(parent.width*0.60); break
                    case 10: -dp(parent.width-parent.width*0.70); break
                    case 11: -dp(parent.width-parent.width*0.70); break
                    }
                }
                y: {
                    switch(indexLocationPopup) {
                    case 0: dp(parent.height-parent.height*0.75); break
                    case 1: dp(parent.height-parent.height*0.75); break
                    case 2: dp(parent.height-parent.height*0.75); break
                    case 3: dp(parent.height-parent.height*0.75); break
                    case 4: dp(parent.height-parent.height*0.75); break
                    case 5: dp(parent.height-parent.height*0.75); break
                    case 6: dp(parent.height-parent.height*0.75); break
                    case 7: dp(parent.height-parent.height*0.75); break
                    case 8: dp(parent.height-parent.height*0.75); break
                    case 9: -dp(parent.height+parent.height*0.30); break
                    case 10: -dp(parent.height+parent.height*0.30); break
                    case 11: -dp(parent.height+parent.height*0.30); break
                    }
                }
                z: ((indexLocationPopup >= 0) && (indexLocationPopup <= 11)) ? 99 : 0
            }
    }
    }
```

ContextMenuEditTile.qml and this is my popup

```
    import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

    Rectangle {

        id:contextMenu
        width: 245; height: 265
        visible: false
        radius: 2;
        color: clrPaletta.tileMenuclr1

        ListView {

            id:listView
            anchors.fill: parent; clip: true;
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

            model: ListModel{

                id: model
                ListElement{ name:qsTr("Accessories"); urlImage: "qrc:/QmlContents/IMG/accessories.png" }
                ListElement{ name:qsTr("Copy");     urlImage: "qrc:/QmlContents/IMG/copy.png" }
                ListElement{ name:qsTr("Rename");  urlImage: "qrc:/QmlContents/IMG/rename_folder.png" }
                ListElement{ name:qsTr("Modify");  urlImage: "qrc:/QmlContents/IMG/move_icon.png" }
                ListElement{ name:qsTr("Delete");   urlImage: "qrc:/QmlContents/IMG/delete_folder.png" }
            }

            delegate: Button{

                id:buttonLista
                width: parent.width; height: listView.height/5

                contentItem: Rectangle {

                    anchors.fill: parent; color: "transparent"
                    opacity: this.down ? 0.80 : 1

                    Rectangle{
                        width: parent.width; height: 1;
                        color: clrPaletta.lineTileContxMenu
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom;
                        visible: model.index < 4 ? true : false
                    }

                    Text {
                        id:testoItem
                        text: qsTr(name)
                        font.capitalization: Font.Capitalize; font.family: myVar.fontTile
                        color: clrPaletta.black; font.pixelSize: 18
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.leftMargin: 65
                    }

                    Image {
                        id:imageList
                        source: urlImage
                        anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.leftMargin: 20
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a `Item { id: overlay }` that is last in `main.qml`, this way it is guaranteed to be on top of the rest of the content, and show up your popup parented to the overlay.

It will be better to have at most one of those at a time and centered in the screen for better user experience. You could however map the particular tile position to the screen to have the popup appear relative to it.

It will also be nice if the popup has an underlay that fills the "empty" area, so clicking outside of the popup closes it.

This means you won't have to bother with any manual z ordering whatsoever. Besides, it would only work for close siblings and such, good luck achieving the desired results in your use case...

Here is a quick example how you could reuse a single popup menu and have it connected to an arbitrary item to access its functionality:

```
Window {
  visible: true
  width: 600
  height: 300

  GridView {
    id: view
    model: 6
    anchors.fill: parent
    cellWidth: 200
    cellHeight: 150

    delegate: Rectangle {
      id: dlg
      width: 200
      height: 150
      color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1)
      function foo() { return index }
      MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: menu.item = dlg // to open the menu for this item
      }
    }
  }

  Item { // the overlay
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: menu.item
    MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: parent
      onClicked: menu.item = null // close the menu
    }
    Rectangle {
      color: "black"
      anchors.fill: parent
      opacity: .5
    }
    Rectangle {
      color: "white"
      anchors.fill: menu
      anchors.margins: -10
    }
    Column {
      id: menu
      anchors.centerIn: parent
      property Item item: null
      Button {
        text: "index"
        onClicked: console.log(menu.item.foo())
      }
      Button {
        text: "color"
        onClicked: console.log(menu.item.color)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific on the item suggestion? thanks

Comment: @sebba23 see the trivial example I added

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create your context menu dynamically with `SwipeView` component set as parent:

```
var comp = Qt.createComponent("ContextMenuEditTile.qml");
var contextMenu = comp.createObject(view);
```

With this solution you do not need to struggle around with z-index values. At least when you use asynchonous `Loader` component the z-index will not work at all.

After creating the context menu you have to set your x and y values accordingly:

```
contextMenu.x = (your big switch case)
contextMenu.y = (your big switch case)
contextMenu.visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read that first : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop
the Z property order sibling items.

The problem here is only hierarchy, try to change your root, use rect or other instead of swipeview and make your swipeview and your button its childrens.

Comment: Could someone explain with z-order is not a valid answer?